# How do I know if query is executed correctly or not while executing the cursor.execute()?

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

```
query = "delete from mytable where id =10"
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
```

It returns None but I want to know the response of the query. How do I get the result?

Same as insert statement also. Could anyone give me the solution?

Comment: `cursor.fetchall ()` ? or `cursor.fetchone()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look at docs:

**Django / DB docs**: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

The object django.db.connection represents the default database connection, and django.db.transaction represents the default database transaction. To use the database connection, call connection.cursor() to get a cursor object. Then, call cursor.execute(sql, [params]) to execute the SQL and cursor.fetchone() or cursor.fetchall() to return the resulting rows.

And Mysql / Python docs:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm

Commit after executing the query :

```
# Prepare SQL query to DELETE required records
sql = "delete from mytable where id =10"
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()
```

I hope this helps.